# Hiding the keyboard in S40 Lwuit Nokia

Tags: java-me, keyboard, lwuit, nokia-s40

I don't find the way to do a simple this like hide the keyboard when I want to.
I've a `Command`and a `TextField`. The user can write in the `TextField`and when he press the command the keyboard must hide, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the way to do that!

Using `Component.requestFocus()` in other `Component` of the `Form`, the keyboard hides!

Does Anyone know other way?

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure but try something like this...

com.sun.lwuit.VirtualKeyboard.getVirtualKeyboard(myTextField).setVisible(false);